# Proving that $\exists t \in \mathbb R: ||t u|| = d(0,K)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's consider $\mathbb R^n$ with the usual inner product $\cdot$, norm $||\cdot||$ and distance $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ induced by that inner product.

If $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $a \in \mathbb R^n$ we can define $d(a,X) := \inf \{d(a,x) : x \in X\}$.

Let $K$ be a Hyperplane, meaning that $\exists p \in \mathbb R^n$, and $\exists S \leq \mathbb R^n$ with $\dim S = n - 1$ such that:

$$K = \{p\}  + S$$

Let $u \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $u$ spans $S^\perp$, so $\{u\}$ is a basis of $S^\perp$.

Then:

$$\exists t \in \mathbb R: ||t u|| = d(0,K)$$

---

I came up with this by observing some specific cases in $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ and this was my attempt of generalizing. It's easy to intuitively understand why this is true in $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ but I'm not being able to prove this for any $\Bbb R^n$. So my questions are:

1. Is this even true for $\Bbb R^n$?
2. If so, how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $d(0,K) \le \|p\|$ since certainly $p \in K$. Therefore we can take the infimum over $K \cap \overline{B}(0,p)$ without changing anything:
$$d(0,K) = \inf\{\|x\|:x \in K\} = \inf\{\|x\|:x \in K \cap \overline{B}(0,p)\}$$
and the latter is an infimum of a continuous function over a compact set so it is attained. Hence let $x_0 \in K \cap \overline{B}(0,p)$ be such that $d(0,K) = \|x_0\|$.

Now if we define $t := \frac{\|x_0\|}{\|u\|} \in \Bbb{R}$ then
$$\|tu\| = t\|u\| = \frac{\|x_0\|}{\|u\|}\|u\| = \|x_0\| = d(0,K).$$

Comment: Nice proof, loved how you used topology to solve this problem. but I was trying to find one that only uses linear algebra concepts.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Sure, here is a different proof. Notice that we can always write $K = q+S$ for some $q \in S^\perp$. Indeed, let $S = \{v\}^\perp$ where $v \in \Bbb{R}^n$ is a unit vector. Then $$K = p+S = \underbrace{\langle p,v\rangle v}_{\perp S} + \underbrace{(p-\langle p,v\rangle v)}_{\perp v \implies \in S} + S = q+S $$
with $q := \langle p,v\rangle v$. Now by Pythagoras we have $$d(0,K)^2 = \inf\{\|q+x\|^2 : x \in S\} = \inf\{\|q\|^2 + \|x\|^2 : x \in S\} = \|q\|^2$$
since $0 \in S$. Therefore $d(0,K) = \|q\|$ so we can set $t := \frac{\|q\|}{\|u\|}$.